# Do these generalization of riemannian/semi-riemannian geometry have names?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

In Riemannian geometry we require that the metric $g$ be a positive definite real matrix and in semi-Riemannian geometry we relax this requirement and instead ask that the metric be a non degenerate symmetric matrix. If we relax further and simply ask that the matrix be non degenerate, that is, we allow for asymmetric matrices with non zero determinant, what kind of object do we get? Does this object have a name?

Similarly, if we generalize further and allow the matrix to be any complex matrix with non zero determinant, does this have a name?

Finally, what if we allow the matrix to be complex valued but require it to be self adjoint, what is this called?

I would like to know if any of these objects have been studied and if so what they are called. Any references are greatly appreciated. If you need clarification please let me know.

Comment: I'm not too sure about other types of geometries, but if you assume skew-symmetry, non-degeneracy and the form being closed (exterior derivative vanishing), then the $g$ is typically denoted as $\omega$, and this is the setting of symplectic geometry

Comment: thanks for this, I'm basically interested in as many of these generalizations as possible. If you know any more then please let me know. If you think you have a comprehensive list then that would constitute an answer to my question. Thanks again

Comment: A _hermitian manifold_ is the generalization of a Riemannian geometry to complex numbers. It has a metric tensor that must be self-adjoint to satisfy the usual metric requirements. From there we get a _semi-hermitian manifold_ if we drop the positive definiteness and allow negative distances.

Comment: Any asymmetric bilinear form can be decomposed into a symmetric and antisymmetric part. Under certain conditions this can give rise to a (pseudo-/sub-)Riemannian metric and/or a symplectic form. If both arise, they form Kähler structure, assuming some additional compatibility conditions.